# How do i get the current_post of my custom post type with the single post?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I was trying to get my custom post types index in the single post. But I am only getting -1 as the index. The only possible error here could be calling the `$the_query->current_post` outside the while loop. But Here I am calling it inside the loop. Someone please tell me what my missing here or doing wrong.

Here is my single_post.php

```
<?php
    $counter = 0;
    $total = $count_posts;
    while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();
    $args2 = array(
        'post_type' => 'award',
        'meta_key' => '',
        'meta_value' => get_the_ID($the_query),
        'tax_query' => array(
            array (
                'taxonomy' => 'awardtype',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $term_ID,
            )
        ),
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args2 );
    $index = $the_query->current_post;
    echo "Current Post".$index;
    $count_posts = $the_query->post_count;
    $designation = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'designation', true);
    $winner_team = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'winner_team', true);
    $feedback_provider_name = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'feedback_provider_name', true);
    $year = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'year', true);
    $terms=get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'awardtype' );         

?> 
<main class="award-page__wrapper">
    <div class="z-container">
        <section class="testimonial-main__section">
            <div class="testimonial-main__block">
                <div class="testimonial-inner__block">
                    <div class="feather-emblem__shape">
                        <?php 
                        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) :
                        ?>
                            <img class="winner-profile-pic" alt="Profile pic" height="100" width="100" loading="lazy" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>"/>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <img class="winner-profile-pic" height="100" width="100" loading="lazy" src="Avatar.png" alt="Profile pic" />
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="label-ribbon">
                        <span class="label-ribbon__text"><?php foreach($terms as $term){echo $term->name;}?> Performer</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="testimonial-text__area">
                        <h2 class="testimonial-heading"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <h3 class="testimonial-subheading"><?php echo $designation; ?> <span class="gray-dot"></span> <?php echo $winner_team; ?></h3>
                        <div class="testimonial-description">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </div>
                        <p class="testimonial-candidate__name"><?php echo $feedback_provider_name; ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="testimonial-prev__next">
                        <?php
                        $prev_post = get_previous_post($in_same_term = true,$excluded_terms = '',$taxonomy = 'awardtype');
                        if($prev_post) {
                               echo "\t" . '<a class="testimonial-next" rel="prev" href="' . get_permalink($prev_post->ID) . '" title="' . $prev_title. '" class=" "></a>' . "\n";
                            }
                        $next_post = get_next_post($in_same_term = true,$excluded_terms = '',$taxonomy = 'awardtype' );
                        if($next_post) {
                            echo "\t" . '<a class="testimonial-prev" rel="next" href="' . get_permalink($next_post->ID) . '" title="' . $next_title. '" class=" "></a>' . "\n";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <?php 
        if ($counter == $total)
        {
        // echo('test');
        }
        ?>
        <?php if ($term->name == "Outstanding")
        {?>
        <a class="view-performers View-star-Performers" href="/star" title="View star Performers">View Performers <svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M8 0L6.6 1.4L12.2 7H0V9H12.2L6.6 14.6L8 16L16 8L8 0Z"  fill="#f7d0cc"/> </svg></a>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($term->name == "star")
        {?>
        <a class="view-performers View-Outstanding-Performers" href="/outstanding" title="View Outstanding Performers">View Performers <svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M8 0L6.6 1.4L12.2 7H0V9H12.2L6.6 14.6L8 16L16 8L8 0Z" fill="#af864e"/> </svg></a>
            <?php } ?>
    </div>
</main><!-- #main -->

<?php
if (($the_query->current_post + 1) == $the_query->post_count) {
    // echo '<div>Your code place here';

}
$counter++;
endwhile; // End of the loop.
//echo($count_posts);
  ?>
```

Comment: _"But Here I am calling it inside the loop"_ - in the loop over the result of the "global" query, yes. But you are trying to get the index of the post from your own query that you are making with those `$args2` parameters here - and over _that_ query result, you are not currently looping.

Comment: Thanks for your response you were correct I was not looping with $the_query. Now its working fine.